# How to prevent two events from being fired?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I added a `ListSelectionListener` to a JTable so that when I select a row, I get the object whose values I used to populate that row. But when I select the row, I noticed that two events are fired: one for column selection, I presume, and another for row selection. Is there a way in which I can prevent two events from being fired? I set the table selection mode to `SINGLE_SELECTION`. Here is my code:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()); 
    SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 0);
    System.err.println(someObject);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check the value of `event.getValueIsAdjusting()` before doing anything.

If that returns true, you can ignore the event because it is "*one in a series of multiple events, where changes are still being made*" (quote from the Javadocs)

[`getValueIsAdjusting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29)

[`setValueIsAdjusting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setValueIsAdjusting%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're getting two events from de/selection: the first occurrence would be the deselection of the old item, and the subsequent event would be the selection of the new one.

If you store the object of the previous selection (`getSource()`?) outside of this event, and then check to see if the current event has the same object as the last event. If so, you can assume that the event you're currently analyzing is just being deselected, having been selected previously. If they're not equal, then update your external variable and actually run whatever code you want to run.